# Node JavaScript express JavaScript format data get from the sequlize query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using sequlize in express JavaScript framework.

```
const data = await db.Tour.findAll();
res.status(200).json(data)
```

If I do this I can nicely retrieve the data in the front-end vue JavaScript spa like this

```
{
    tour_name:"Bali",
    activities:[
        {name:"Swimming"},
        {name:"Beach vollyball"},
    ]
}
```

Above one is for retrieve the data for front-end.

If I need to get the data and make some changes in the controller before send them, I will raw: true
then I can get the same output in my controller. But the problem is **raw: true** is not going well with the
joins, so that point getting the data from the controller and make some changes to it is very hard.
I have to access so many nested objects to find the data I want. Is there a smarter way (there should be) to get the above format
from the controller without using the **raw: true**.

I hope there must be a nice way to pass that data object to some thing and convert to the format.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure what you need `raw` for: can't you already alter `data` in your controller as is? Maybe show a more complete example, with all your joins and nesting? (If what you show is what you get on the client, it should be no different from what you pass to `res.json`, right?)

Comment: I can alter data but I need to go deep something.dataValues like so. I want a simple form. Of cause this sample data. As far as I know We can use `raw:true` with complex joins?

Comment: I don't know about `raw` limitations, but you can always use intermediate variables to store the path to a nested object (everything being _references_ in JS), so that the code doesn't look too verbose. Anyway if your data has many levels of depth, if you want to alter it you will need to tell JS the path to the data at some point.

Answer (score 0):

In below code I had to retrieve a shops products images and its ids along with some other data like ratings, count etc.

```
In below code I had to retrieve a shop products images and its ids.


exports.filterShopListings = async (data) => {

    return Db.sequelize.query("SELECT productImages, S.shopId, S.currency, S.mainImage, S.mainImageThumb, S.coverImage, S.coverImageThumb, S.name, S.location, S.approved, S.locationLatitude, CONCAT('"+process.env.QR_URL+"',S.qrCode) as qrCode, S.locationLongitude, COALESCE(productCount,0) as productCount, COALESCE(ratingCount,0) as ratingCount, COALESCE(ROUND(UR.ratingAvg,1) ,0) as ratings, COALESCE(shopFollowing,0) as followingCount FROM shops as S JOIN users U ON (U.userId=S.userId AND U.blocked='0') LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) as productCount, shopId, GROUP_CONCAT(mainImageThumb,'--',shopProductId) as productImages FROM shopProducts WHERE shopProducts.deleted='0' AND shopProducts.blocked='0' GROUP BY shopId)  SP ON (SP.shopId=S.shopId) LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) as ratingCount, AVG(ratings) as ratingAvg, shopId FROM userRatings WHERE userRatings.blocked='0' AND userRatings.deleted='0' GROUP BY shopId ) UR ON (UR.shopId=S.shopId) LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) as shopFollowing, shopId FROM shopFollowings GROUP BY shopId) SF ON (SF.shopId=S.shopId) WHERE "+data.whereString+" HAVING "+data.havingString+" ORDER BY "+data.orderingParam+" "+data.orderingSort+" LIMIT "+data.skip+", "+data.take+" ",{ type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
        .then( (shops) => {

            shops = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(shops));

            shops.forEach(  (shop) => {

                //shop.productImagesTemp  = shop.productImages;
                shop.productImages = shopImagesFunc(shop.productImages);

            });

            return shops;

        });

};
```

And The shopImagesFunc Code -

```
    var shopImagesFunc = (productImages) => {

    if(productImages ==null)
        return [];

    var images = (productImages.split(",").filter(Boolean));

    var newImages = [];
    images.forEach(image => {

        let temp = image.split("--").filter(Boolean);

        newImages.push({
            shopProductId: parseInt(temp[1]),
            mainImage: temp[0],
        });

    });

    return newImages;

};
```

SQL Query is little complicated but creating a common function to format into required output would be very useful.